# Read a file with dynamic file name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, excel

Is it possible to read a file with file name as Sometext_ddmmyy.xls in JavaScript?
The file name changes daily but date ddmmyy are random date in that week or previous.
But the path of the file never changes.
Can you help to code in JavaScript to read the file?

Code:

```
var filename =  /^path\\sometext_.*.xls$/;
....
var neobjectexcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var sheet = neojectexcel.Workbooks.Open(filename).ActiveSheet;
...
```

I used Regex but I am getting "Sorry, we couldn't find /^path\sometext_.*.xls$/ Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?" Error!

Even the regex `/^path\\sometext_\d\d\d\d\d\d.xls$/` is giving the same error.

Also tried \d+ instead of \d\d\d\d\d\d does not works.
Please help!

Update: The file will be in a folder on a server along with other files of similar names like sometext_ddmmyy.xls randomtext_ddmmyy.xls randomothertext_ddmmyy.xls and will be accessed with script on the same server.

Comment: Help me understand: you want to access one file, this file exists on the folder all alone, no other files will ever exist in the same location, the file name will change every day. Is this correct?

Comment: @AGE No, the folder have more than just this file, it will be of different names, like sometext_ddmmyy.xls randomtext_ddmmyy.xls and so! And yes, I want to access one file at a time! And yes, the file name changes everyday!

Comment: Do these files exist locally or in a server?

Comment: @AGE they are on server local drive, accessed from the same server with the script.

Comment: Hmm...The Excel method takes a string as a parameter, not a RegExp literal.

Comment: @Teemu oh, even wild card is not working, is there any other way to achieve the same without regex?

Comment: Indeed, I checked the docs, just type of string, no mention of wildcards.

Comment: @Teemu I just have to open and read data from a file with file name like sometext_ddmmyy.xls. This ddmmyy keeps changing daily and don't want to change code everyday as per the ddmmyy change!

Comment: Yes, I read your question a bit poorly, sorry for that. Can you use other ActiveX objects, like FileSystemObject?

Comment: @Teemu I am not familiar with FileSystemObject, will I be able to achieve the requirement if I use FileSystemObject? If yes, can you let me know how?

Comment: With FSO you could read all the files from a specific folder, then check the date of creation, and get the filename you need.

Comment: @Teemu oh, that won't work, while running the script, we might not know the ddmmyy part, and the file creation date and time were also unknown. The only part that is known is that there will be few files of different name with ddmmyy at the end of the filename. And script uses this file to get current data. The ddmmyy part range from past week to next week giving 20-21 possibilities, but may also change!

Comment: You an extract the name of the latest file without knowing when it was created, if that's what you need?

Comment: @Teemu there will be only one file with that name in the folder, so yeah latest file of the filename will work too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `FileSystemObject` you can filter a filename with a RegExp and find the latest filtered file added to a folder like so:

```
function getLatestFile (path, filter) {
    var fileIO = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
        folder = fileIO.GetFolder(path), // Get a folder object
        files = new Enumerator(folder.files), // Create files collection
        latest = 0,
        file, date, isTargetFile, temp, target;
    while (!files.atEnd()) { // Iterate files collection
        file = files.item(); // Get a file from the collection
        temp = new String(file); // Convert a file object to string
        isTargetFile = filter.test(temp); // Filter the filename
        date = new Date(file.DateCreated).getTime(); // Get the creation date of the file
        if (isTargetFile && date > latest) { // Check if this file passed the filter and is newer than the previous filter-passed file
            target = temp;
            latest = date;
        }
        files.moveNext(); // Continue iteration
    }
    return target;
}
```

An example call for your case would be:

```
var filename = getLatestFile(path_to_folder, /sometext_\d{6}\.xls$/);
```

Arguments: `path` = the path to the folder where to search files. `filter` = a RegExp object (literal or constructed) to filter the filename. When creating the RegExp, note that the converted file object (`temp`) uses a backslash as a folder separator, though the RegExp can be created to filter the filename only. If the function returns `undefined`, none of the filenames has matched the RegExp.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the filename as variable in getLatestFile(path_to_folder, /"FilenamefromVariable"_\d{6}\.xls$//); instead of "sometext" which is predefined before the script runs, we want to pass it with a value from variable, that's read from another file. I can get the value in the variable for the file name, but need to know is it possible to pass it along with the Regex pattern into the function?

Comment: @vikrammohan `filter` is a RegExp object, as I've stated in the answer, it is "_literal or constructed_", i.e. you can create the RegExp as you need before calling `getLatestFile`. See [RegExp Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for further details.

Comment: I tried var nameoffile = new RegExp(nameofvariable + "_\d{6}\.xls$/"); but I get the result as undefined and value of nameoffile is /sometext\r_\d{6}\.xls$\//. But the value of nameoffile should be sometext_\d{6}\.xls$/ to make it work perfect with getLatestFile(). Could you please help me get what mistake I am making in Regex construction?

Comment: Please read the docs, for example, you need to double the backslash in a string, otherwise it escapes the next character. Like so: `new RegExp(nameofvariable + "_\\d{6}\\.xls$");`. And no RexExp literal markup, i.e. preceding and trailing slashes should be included.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! nameofvariable = nameofvariable.trim(); Var nameoffile = new RegExp(nameofvariable + "_\\d{6}\\.xls$"); the extra null,/r at the end of the value is causing the issue. Thanks again!