# Opening a .txt file created with one function and opening that .txt file with another function

Tags: javascript, html, hta

Trying to open the created notepad file (created from my submitOrder function) with the "OpenFile" function but however I cant get it to work.  Please help the error i get is "the system cannot find the file specified" how do I alter my "openFile" function in order to open the file created.

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
 function submitOrder(file)
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject ("scripting.filesystemobject")
var newfile = fso.createTextFile (file,true);
var string = "";
var orderlist = document.getElementById("orderlist");

for (i=0; i < orderlist.length; i++)
{
    if ( orderlist.options[i].text != "list of ordered items" )
    {
        string = string + orderlist.options[i].text +  '\r\n';
    }
}

newfile.WriteLine(string); 
newfile.Close();
alert('Your order has been submitted to the text file ' + file);
}

function OpenFile(file)
{
wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wshell.run("Z:\Local\eric.mahinay\Assignment 4 Programming" + file ,1,false);
}
```

**FOLLOWING HTML CODE:**

```
<body onload="screen();">

 <h1>Gigantuano Pizza Company</h1>

 <p>Place your order now!</p>

  <select id="pizza" >
  <option value="0.00">Select a pizza</option>
  <option value="10.00">Hawaiian - Large Stuffed Crust - $10.00</option>
  <option value="8.00">Hawaiian - XL Standard Base - $8.00</option>
  <option value="13.50">Hawaiian - XL Stuffed Crust - $13.50</option>
  <option value="10.00">Beef and Onion - Large Stuffed Crust - 
  $10.00</option>
  <option value="8.00">Beef and Onion - XL Standard Base - $8.00</option>
  <option value="13.50">Beef and Onion - XL Stuffed Crust - $13.50</option>
  <option value="11.00">Peperoni Lovers - Large Stuffed Crust - 
  $11.00</option>
  <option value="13.50">Chicken Supreme - Large Stuffed Crust - 
  $13.50</option>
  </select>

  <input type ="button" onclick="addOrderItem()" value="Add Order Item"><br>
  <br>
  Ordered Items:  click to check order
  <select id="orderlist"><option value="0.00">list of ordered items</option>
  </select>
  <input type ="button" onclick="removeOrderItem();" value="Remove Order 
  Item">

  <br>
  Order Total: <input type ="text" id="ordertotal" value=0.0></input><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  Type your order submission file name (one word):<input type ="text" 
  id="orderfilename" value=""></input>
  Click to submit your order: 
  <input type ="button" 
  onclick="submitOrder(document.getElementById('orderfilename').value + 
  '.txt');" value="Submit Order">
  <input type="button" value="Open Order Text File" onclick="OpenFile( 
  document.getElementById('orderfilename').value + '.txt' );"/>
  <br>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The path is incorrect, should be `'"Z:\\Local\\eric.mahinay\\Assignment 4 Programming\\' + file + '"'`. The backslash in JS is the escape character which must be escaped when including the backslash to a string. Notice also the trailing path separator before filename, and the double quotes, they are needed when the path contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks, ill test this out when I can ASAP and ill get back to you with the results. However I have another question, is it possible to alter this code in order to find and open the "file" if it is not saved within the specified "path"

Comment: Searching a file is possible, but it is not just a line or two of code. You could ask a new question, though it also better to try something before asking. There's my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426269/1169519), but it's searches a file from a known folder, there will be a lot to do to change the code to search from a folder structure.